# Why am I getting a MySQL Syntax Error when doing Subqueries?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Below is my query that need to make views from the sub queries and then run the math at the top. I get a syntax error when I run it. I have done subqueries before so I may just be tired and do not see the issue.

```sql
SELECT  STDDEV(north.value)AS north, 
        STDDEV(south.value)AS south, 
        STDDEV(west.value) AS west, 
        STDDEV(east.value) AS east 
FROM ( 
        SELECT `series_id`, 
                value 
        FROM   `current` 
        WHERE (( 
                    SUBSTRING(series_id,5,4) = '0100' 
                AND SUBSTRING(series_id,9,8) = 'SETA' 
                AND theyear>= (2000) 
                AND theyear <=(2012) 
                AND period = 'M13') as north 
            OR ( 
                    substring(series_id,5,4) = '0200' 
                AND substring(series_id,9,8) = 'SETA' 
                AND theyear>= (2000) 
                AND theyear <=(2012) 
                AND period = 'M13') AS south 
            OR ( 
                    substring(series_id,5,4) = '0300' 
                AND substring(series_id,9,8) = 'SETA' 
                AND theyear>= (2000) 
                AND theyear <=(2012) 
                AND period = 'M13') AS west 
            OR ( 
                    substring(series_id,5,4) = '0400' 
                AND substring(series_id,9,8) = 'SETA' 
                AND theyear>= (2000) 
                AND theyear <=(2012) 
                AND period = 'M13') AS east
            )
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS north OR
>               (
>                 SUBSTRING(series_id,5,4) = '0200' AND
>     ' at line 17

Comment: Please organize your query so that it's more readable. No one will find the missing close parenthesis for you.

Comment: What should it look like?

Comment: Can you update with the syntax error did you say?

Comment: @BrunoCésarsyntax error updated

Comment: You can't add aliases in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

I give it a start with re-formatting:

```
SELECT STDDEV(north.value)AS North,
       STDDEV(south.value)as South,
       STDDEV(west.value) as West,
       STDDEV(east.value) AS East

FROM (
    SELECT `series_id`, 
            value
      FROM `CURRENT`
     WHERE (
            (
              SUBSTRING(series_id,5,4) = '0100' AND
              SUBSTRING(series_id,9,8) = 'SETA' AND
              theYear>= (2000) AND
              theYear <=(2012) AND
              period = 'M13'
            ) AS north OR
            (
              SUBSTRING(series_id,5,4) = '0200' AND
              SUBSTRING(series_id,9,8) = 'SETA' AND
              theYear>= (2000) AND
              theYear <=(2012) AND
              period = 'M13'
            ) as south OR
            (
            SUBSTRING(series_id,5,4) = '0300' AND
            SUBSTRING(series_id,9,8) = 'SETA' AND
            theYear>= (2000) AND
            theYear <=(2012) AND
            period = 'M13'
            ) as west OR
            (
            SUBSTRING(series_id,5,4) = '0400' AND
            SUBSTRING(series_id,9,8) = 'SETA' AND
            theYear>= (2000) AND
            theYear <=(2012) AND 
            period = 'M13'
            ) as east
          )
```

It looks like you are missing the parenthesis terminating your subquery. You should add an alias as well... like this:

```
) subquery
```

That's just from the top of my head. I can't run MySQL on the machine I'm currently on. Also, you did not attach the actual syntax error message, that makes it hard as well.

Note also that "value" and "current" are [reserved words in many DBMS and the SQL standard](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/sql-reserved-words.tml) and while they are not in MySQL, I would still try to choose a better name for the field/column. Makes it easier to migrate your schema and possibly future-proofs it too.

EDIT: However, in your inner query you are only selecting `series_id` and `value` and not `north.value`, `south.value`, `west.value`, `east.value`. So the outer query will still fail. There is a structural problem in your query as these 4 fields should be moved from the condition into the SELECT part of the inner query.

Comment: Issue is still the subquery "as" lines that is where my errors are at

Comment: `AS` makes no sense in the WHERE clause. `AS` should be in the SELECT part of the query (see my EDIT post).

Comment: It is very hard to understand for others how to re-write this query if you don't give them your schema and tell them what you want to get out of this query. The syntax error is not the problem here - it's the query structure... I recommend posting a new question providing the schema, the query and what data you would like to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  `series_id`, FORMAT(STDDEV(Q2.value),5) 
FROM ( 
    SELECT `series_id`, 
            `value`,
            `theYear`
    FROM   `CURRENT` 
    WHERE (( 
                SUBSTRING(series_id,5,4) = '0100' 
            AND SUBSTRING(series_id,9,8) = 'SETA' 
            AND theyear>= (2000) 
            AND theyear <=(2012) 
            AND period = 'M13') 
        OR ( 
                substring(series_id,5,4) = '0200' 
            AND substring(series_id,9,8) = 'SETA' 
            AND theyear>= (2000) 
            AND theyear <=(2012) 
            AND period = 'M13')  
        OR ( 
                substring(series_id,5,4) = '0300' 
            AND substring(series_id,9,8) = 'SETA' 
            AND theyear>= (2000) 
            AND theyear <=(2012) 
            AND period = 'M13') 
        OR ( 
                    substring(series_id,4,1) = 'R'
            AND    substring(series_id,5,4) = '0400' 
            AND substring(series_id,9,8) = 'SETA' 
            AND theyear>= (2000) 
            AND theyear <=(2012)
            )
           )
          )     AS Q2
          GROUP BY `series_id`
```